# Project reference to access Umbraco content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco6

MVC & C# newbie here.  Wanting to add a form to an Umbraco V6.1.5 web site that contains dropdowns containing existing Umbraco content. I understand I need to create a controller and model and partial view. However, my issue is I don't know where to put them. In VS2012 I have a solution with two projects, one is Umbraco and one is an emailer project that has umbraco.dll references in it.  I build it and drop the dll in to Umbraco's bin folder and all is well. Now I need access to the Umbraco content from the emailer project and I don't know how to get it. I've tried adding a few references but non have worked. Am I going about this totally the wrong way?

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try including the following dlls in your emailer project:

- businesslogic.dll
- cms.dll
- interfaces.dll
- Umbraco.Core.dll
- umbraco.dll

Then you can use the things like uQuery and Node to get what you need.